# Flatpickr Calendar - How to Disable listed dates and weekends

Tags: javascript, date, flatpickr

I am using flatpickr.js for my calendar. I want to disable some listed dates together with Saturdays and Sundays.  Disabling Sat and Sun works well using the following code. However for the listed dates, only the first date is disabled. Why not the rest? What am I doing wrong?

```
        function rmydays(date) {
            return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
        }

        var $rdated_data = '"10-16-2019", "10-22-2019", "10-25-2019"';  

        $("#retail-calendar").flatpickr({
                enableTime: true,
                inline: true,
                dateFormat: m-d-Y,                    
                disable: [$rdated_data, rmydays ],                  
                locale: {
                     firstDayOfWeek: 1
                    }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are using both concrete dates and functions in "disable", can you try:

```
    function rmySpecificdays(date) {
        const rdatedData = ["2019-10-16", "2019-10-22", "2019-10-25"]; 
        return rdatedData.includes(date.toISOString().substring(0, 10));
    }

    function rmydays(date) {
        return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
    }

    $("#retail-calendar").flatpickr({
            enableTime: true,
            inline: true,
            dateFormat: m-d-Y,                    
            disable: [rmydays, rmySpecificdays],                  
            locale: {
                 firstDayOfWeek: 1
                }
    });
```

Comment: Does not seem too work. No date is disabled besides weekends.

Comment: if you set function rmySpecificdays(date) {return true;} does it disable all dates?

Comment: Yes. It disables everything. All dates on the calendar

Comment: ok, so then the contains logic is flawed, will write the code in a sec

Comment: edited my answer, tested on https://repl.it/repls/DevotedFrozenAdaware

Comment: Yes now dates are disabled but something not right. It adds 1 day to the date.  Instead of disabling 16th it disabled 17, 22nd -> 23rd, 25th -> 26th

Comment: not sure why, can you debug/print the "date" object to see if it's the right one? I have a stupid suggestion, but until you find the actual issue, why not put 16 instead 17, 21 instead of 22 ... and so on

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make it work using this format:

```
    "disable": [
        // Disable weekends
        function(date) {
            return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);

        },
        // Disable specific dates
        "2022-03-25",
        "2022-03-10",
        "2022-03-04" 
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer using the toISOString() function does not work as expected. It disables the day after the one listed in the array.

The toISOString() method returns the date in UTC, not in local time. I was able to correctly compare the dates with this custom function:

```
function toISODate(d) {
    const z = n => ('0' + n).slice(-2);
    return d.getFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + z(d.getDate()); 
}
```

I found the solution in the flatpickr issues: https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/issues/2426

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "disable": [ function(date) {
            // return true to disable
            return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);

        }
       
    ],
    "locale": {
        "firstDayOfWeek": 1 // start week on Monday
    }
}

https://flatpickr.js.org/getting-started/

You will get all the sloutions related to date disabled and minDate and maxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

based on @horatiu-jeflea  and @marloes provided solutions, I used below code to fix my similar issue with multiple pickers hope it might help someone.

```
       var disableDates =  [
            function(date) {
                // return true to disable
                return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);

            },
            function(date) {                    
                const rdatedData = ["2022-01-01","2022-04-30","2022-05-01","2022-05-02","2022-05-03","2022-05-04","2022-07-08","2022-07-09","2022-07-10","2022-07-11","2022-07-30","2022-10-08","2022-12-01","2022-12-02","2022-12-03"]; 
                return rdatedData.includes (toISODate(date)) ;
            },
        ];
        var Fp_options_cfg = {
            altInput: true,
            altFormat: "d M Y",
            dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
            onChange: [],                
            "disable": disableDates,
            "locale": {
                "firstDayOfWeek": 1 // start week on Monday
            },
           
        };
        InputLeaveFrom = flatpickr("#InputLeaveFrom", Fp_options_cfg);
        InputLeaveFrom.config.onChange.push(function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            InputLeaveTo.set('minDate', selectedDates[0]);
            InputLastWorkingDate.set('maxDate', new Date(dateStr).fp_incr(-1) );
        } );
        InputLeaveTo = flatpickr("#InputLeaveTo", Fp_options_cfg);
        InputLeaveTo.config.onChange.push(function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            InputLeaveFrom.set('maxDate', selectedDates[0]);
            InputResumptionDate.set('minDate', new Date(dateStr).fp_incr(1) );
        } );
        InputLastWorkingDate = flatpickr("#InputLastWorkingDate", Fp_options_cfg);
        InputLastWorkingDate.config.onChange.push(function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            InputLeaveFrom.set('minDate', new Date(dateStr).fp_incr(1) );
                        
        } );
        InputResumptionDate = flatpickr("#InputResumptionDate", Fp_options_cfg);
        InputResumptionDate.config.onChange.push(function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            InputLeaveTo.set('maxDate', new Date(dateStr).fp_incr(-1) );
            
        } );

        function toISODate(d) {
             const z = n => ('0' + n).slice(-2);
             return d.getFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + 
             z(d.getDate()); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but adding this here as I just stumbled upon this thread.

You can set your function equal to a variable and include that in the disable array like:

```
let rmydays = function(date) {
    return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
}

var $rdated_data = '"10-16-2019", "10-22-2019", "10-25-2019"';  

$("#retail-calendar").flatpickr({
        enableTime: true,
        inline: true,
        dateFormat: m-d-Y,                    
        disable: [$rdated_data, rmydays ],                  
        locale: {
             firstDayOfWeek: 1
        }
 });
```